# Running VMware on Windows 10 (not the other way around)

Tags: vmware-player, windows-10

Windows 10 is currently downloading on one of my machines. That particular machine has VMware Player 6.0.7 installed on it, running several virtual machines (which are important to me). I couldn't find anything related to installing and running VMware Player on Windows 10; every article I found mentioned setting up a Windows 10 machine on VMP (which I know from experience it works).

Since no explicit material (that I found) addressed the support or lack thereof for VMware Player on Windows 10, I tend to believe that there won't be any problems.

Are there any problems with installing/running VMware Player on Windows 10? Has someone already installed Windows 10 and could run VMP without any problems?

Comment: Seeing as you say these virtual machines are important to you, you should probably have checked this before installing Windows 10.

Comment: Sure, point taken. As I wrote, Windows 10 was downloading, not installing. I've postponed the actual information until I get to do a complete backup of the data. If it would have been installed, I would have already known the answer...

Comment: VMWare Player 7 supports Windows 10 because Workstation 11 supports it

Comment: Do you need this exact version of VMWare Player for any reasons? I'm using the most current version of it on a Windows 10 host. No Problems so far. All my VMs work as usual.

Comment: @Robin no, that was just the installed version at the moment. I have since then upgraded to 7.1.2. Currently still on Windows 7, due to lack of proper drivers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VMware Player 7, which is still free for non-commercial use, has been tested and is working on Windows 10.  Download link for VMware Player 7 can be found here: https://download3.vmware.com/software/player/file/VMware-player-7.1.2-2780323.exe